# Python importation error with Ghost.py

Tags: python, python-module, ghost.py

[Ghost.py is correctly installed, though it can't find it's module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mnoW.png)

Comment: What makes you so sure it is correctly installed?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know where the module is installed? If so is that location in the PYTHONPATH?

Check PYTHONPATH with:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

PYTHONPATH can be modified for the duration of your script using:

```
sys.path.append('/path/to/ghost.py')
```

Or permanently by following these instructions for windows:

[How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)